# NoSuchFieldError when trying to access ArrayList defined in class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to access the ArrayList defined within the class guest. However, I get errors when trying to do so.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

static class guess{
    ArrayList<Integer> box;
    ArrayList<Integer> index;
    int num;
    ArrayList <Boolean> valid;
}
...
guess attempt = new guess();
attempt.box = new ArrayList<Integer>();
attempt.index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
attempt.valid = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

I get the error when attempting "attempt.box.add(some value)"

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I could not reproduce your issue, most likely you're missing important details in your question.  Please try to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {
        static class guess{
            ArrayList<Integer> box;
            ArrayList<Integer> index;
            int num;
            ArrayList <Boolean> valid;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            guess attempt = new guess();
            attempt.box = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            attempt.index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            attempt.valid = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
            attempt.box.add(22);
        }
    }
```